# Get Row number from each cell in selected range in Table with VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables, vba

Well. If I have for example a table with a column "**countries**" and other one **"cities**" And I make a Filter on Countries. How I can get the row number from each register filtered using VBA?

[image]

I like to get rows numbers: 2 and 6.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: iterate through the rows and check if visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ListRows` method of your table, looping through each row.

In this case you can print all the rows in the table that passes your criteria of `Not ...Hidden`.

```
Sub printUnhiddenRows()

    Dim r As ListRow, tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Table1")
    
    For Each r In tbl.ListRows
        If Not r.Range.Rows.Hidden Then Debug.Print r.Range.Row
    Next r

End Sub
```

---

### Some things to remember:

- You may need to change the index number on `Worksheets(1)` if the sheet is not #1 in the worksheet collection.
- You may need to change the table name on `.ListObjects("Table1")` if the table is named something else.

Comment: Dim rngTable As Range
    Dim country As Range
    
    Set rngDB = Range("Table1[Country]")
    rngTable.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    
    For Each country In Selection.Cells
        MsgBox country.Row
    Next

Answer (score 1):

This could be another solution:

```
 Dim rngTable As Range
Dim country As Range
Set rngTable = Range("Table1[Country]")

    rngTable.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    For Each country In Selection.Cells
        MsgBox country.Row
    Next
```